# How to change language to Turkish but only for terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, language-support, 17.04

I am using English , but I cannot understand terminal output clearly, so how to change to Turkish only Terminal?

I try [How to change language only for terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673741/how-to-change-language-only-for-terminal/912606#912606) . But I want to Turkish so I add a line 
`export LANG=tr_TR.utf8`
to the end of .bashrc in my home folder. But it does not work

Comment: @AndroidDev: The OP was asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/912606) to ask a new question. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - I linked a different Q.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Right, but that one is also with English in focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `~/.bashrc` for editing and add these lines at the bottom of it:

```
export LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=tr
```