# strange ls -l output

Tags: command-line, ls

This is a sample output of `ls -l` on my Ubuntu 17.04 box:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 amoro amoro 4096 kvě  6 16:26 myfile
```

There are two parameters that I don't recognize. Counting from left to right, the 6th and the 7th, i.e., kvě and 6 respectively. I googled this but couldn't find an answer. Do you have any clues?

Comment: it should be the date (of last modification of the file). Is kve short for the name of a month in your language?

Comment: Yes, it's the date of the last time the file has been modified. `kvě 6 16:26` is Czech for `May 6 16:26`

Comment: Run: `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ls -l`

Comment: Might be useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/673741/how-to-change-language-only-for-terminal

Comment: Ok that's weird  since the installation language I choose is English. How can I change this? Running this command returns the expected output LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ls -l. But How can I make this change effective?

Comment: @AntonelloMoro `localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8` or change it in this file: `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to work. Also the content of this file /etc/default/locale  was ANG=en_US.utf8. It looks like the problem affects only the date settings of my box. In fact I opened the date setting and found the it was set to Prague. I changed to Rome but the language is still czech

Comment: Ok I managed to solve by setting the locale in language support->regional format. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not all programs interpret the various LC_* settings properly.  For instance, I have LC_CTYPE set to fr_CH (because I exchange emails with clients in Switzerland and like to see the French accents), but some programs would use this to set some or all of their dialogs to French,.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When encountering similar situations, try setting the default `locale` as `en_US`, in your case with the command is `ls -l`, you would run:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ls -l
```

It will produce all output in `en_US` so there will be no confusion.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravexina ravexina  79 Sep 20 2016 test.txt
```

You can change it using:

```
localectl set-locale LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

or only for date:

```
localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_US.utf8
```

then logout and login again, if it did not take effect, reboot your system.

Comment: It works, but how can I make the change effective? I tried localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8, but doesnt work

Comment: Updated my answer ;)

Comment: TIL about `localectl`! I know other locale related commands but not that. Also, why the bias to en_US? :P

Comment: @Zanna Great ;) There is no bias. :D I guess it's just more likely for non native English users (like me) to use `US`. Maybe I'm wrong :D I really don't like `systemd` and it's stuff. so I try to learn more about them and less hating its stuff :))

Comment: I think the usual recommendation to get temporarily English output is to use the C locale

Comment: Will use that from know ;)

Comment: Also, if you want to change all the locale settings to a particular one, use `LC_ALL=xyz`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one on my system

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 zanna zanna 4096 May  5 07:44 custom
```

Left to right we have

- type (directory)
- mode (permissions)
- hardlinks (2)
- owner (zanna)
- group (zanna)
- size (in bytes)
- **month last modified** (May)
- **day of the month last modified** (5th)
- time last modified on that day
- filename

So the fields confusing you are the month and day of the last modification of the file. Kve must be a month or abbreviation of the name of a month in your system locale/language.